# Is there an R function or SQL solution for grouping the all the same numbers repeatedly in a row and assign them to all rows??

Tags: r, amazon-redshift

I want to group the consecutive numbers in a sequence into a single pair. And the final goal is to count the number of pairs per group.

I tried to solve this problem by using a combination of row_number, lag and lead in Redshift.

** I do not care about the decreasing interval, but I want to build the group only in the increasing part.

My table

```
id  number 
ㅡㅡㅡㅡ
a  | 0 
a  | 0 
a  | 1 
a  | 2 
a  | 3 
a  | 2 
a  | 1 
a  | 2 
a  | 1
```

Expected

```
id  number group 
ㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡ
a  | 0   |  0
a  | 0   |  0
a  | 1   |  3
a  | 2   |  3
a  | 3   |  3
a  | 2   |  0
a  | 1   |  2
a  | 2   |  2
a  | 1   |  0
```

Final table

```
group cnt
---------
 2  |  2
 3  |  3
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't understand the expected output. Is group always the count? Similarly, for group 2, why does the 1 get a grouping? For group 3, going from 0 to 1 didn't change the group column. So why would going from 2 to 1 change the group to "2"?

Comment: @Cole Hi Cole, 
what I want is not to worry about decreasing the number, but only considering the increasing number.
In addition, the goal is to grouping the same number according to how many consecutive increases in the increasing section.

Comment: An SQL solution would require a third variable designating the row order. Why is are the four sequential rows a0,a1,a2,a3 in a group with value 4 (would this defy "build the group only in the increasing part"? Or conversely, why is a1, a2 a group = 2 (doesn't this defy "build the group only in the increasing part"), instead of just a2 in a group = 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution (left all steps intentionally in expected data frame):

```
library(dplyr)

df<-tibble(id = "a", number = c(0,0,1,2,3,1,2,1))
expected <- df %>% 
    mutate(l = lag(number), 
           l = if_else(is.na(l), 0, l), 
           splits = l < number & l > 0, #remove & l > 0 if starting from 0 is allowed, change to l + 1 == number if step must be 1
           g = cumsum(!splits)) %>% 
    group_by(g) %>% 
    mutate(group = n()) %>% 
    ungroup()

final <- expected %>% 
    filter(group != 1) %>% 
    group_by(group) %>% 
    summarise(cnt = n())
```

anyway, group and cnt value will always be the same in final table, so you can just use unique(). so I'm not sure if that is what you expected

Comment: This is the solution I want.
Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can toy witht he problematic in a for loop way which identifies the sequence of min. 2 values and assigns the group variable the values of the last number appearing in the sequence. The result can be either the raw dataset providing the group variable or the aggregation

```
X <- data.frame(number = c(0L,0L,1L,2L,3L,2L,1L,2L,1L))

aggrIt <- function(DF = X, raw = T){
  g <- 1L
  result <- rep(0L, nrow(DF))
  for(i in seq_len(nrow(DF))){
    if(i == nrow(DF)) break
    if(i == 1L) {
      if(DF$number[i] != 0L && DF$number[i+1L] == DF$number[i] + 1L) result[i] <- g
      if(DF$number[i] != 0L && DF$number[i+1L] != DF$number[i] + 1L) result[i] <- 0L
                } else {
        if(DF$number[i] != 0L && DF$number[i+1L] == DF$number[i] + 1L) {
          result[i] <- g 
          } else {
              if(DF$number[i-1L] == DF$number[i] - 1L) {
                                                    result[i] <- g
                                                    g <- g + 1L
                                                      }
                  }
      }
  }

  transl <- tapply(DF$number[result != 0L], result[result != 0L], function(i) rep(max(i), length(i)), simplify = F)
  DF$group <- 0L
  DF$group[result %in% names(transl)] <- unlist(transl)
  if(raw) return(DF)
  return(setNames(aggregate(number~group, DF, length, subset = group != 0L), c("group", "cnt")))
}
aggrIt(X, raw= F)
  #group cnt
#1     2   2
#2     3   3
aggrIt(X, raw = T)
  #number group
#1      0     0
#2      0     0
#3      1     3
#4      2     3
#5      3     3
#6      2     0
#7      1     2
#8      2     2
#9      1     0
```

You can apply the function on groups of ids.

Comment: Thank you for answer. This is also a good solution. However, I need to look slowly to understand the whole logic.
Thank you again!